# Apex class in trigger populates lookup based on string input

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, null-pointer

I am writing a trigger on my Case object to run `(before insert)`. I am receiving the following error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CaseTrigger: execution of
>   BeforeInsert
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object
>
> **Class.SiteCoder.run: line 14, column 1**
>   **Class.CaseTriggerHandler.beforeInsert: line 19, column 1**
>   **Trigger.CaseTrigger: line 12, column 1: []**

Line 14 of my class runs the `clean()` method the purpose of which is to take input of potentially fewer than 4 characters and appends leading zeroes until it is 4 characters long.

The casetriggerhandler and casetrigger lines are simply the calls to run this class.

I am having trouble understanding the nature of the error, as I believe I am in the correct context to be able to update the lookup field without additional DML.

### Trigger class

```
public class SiteCoder {

    public static void run(List<Case> newList) {
        system.debug('----SITECODER: ' + newList.size() + ' records to run');

        Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
        for (Case c : newList) {
        String sitecode = c.Web_Site_Code__c;

        if (sitecode.length() < 4){
            clean(sitecode);
        }
        codes.add(sitecode);
        System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Site code added to lookup: ' + sitecode);

        }

        // Use map and list of accounts to take into account possibility of multiple
        // accounts using same site code id
        Map<String, List<Account>> codeAccounts = new Map<String, List<Account>>();
        for (Account a : [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account 
                          WHERE Site_Code_Id__c IN :codes]) {
            if (!codeAccounts.containsKey(a.Site_Code_Id__c)) {
                codeAccounts.put(a.Site_Code_ID__c, new List<Account>());
                System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'First Site Account Found: ' + a.Site_Code_ID__c);
            } else {
                codeAccounts.get(a.Site_Code_ID__c).add(a);
                System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Second Site Account Found: ' + a.Site_Code_ID__c);
            }
        }

        //Update the lookup only if one account matches
        for (Case c : newList) {
            List<Account> matchingAccounts = codeAccounts.get(c.Web_Site_Code__c);
            Id siteId = null;
            if (matchingAccounts != null && matchingAccounts.size() == 1) {
                siteId = matchingAccounts[0].Id;
                System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Account found for site: ' + c.Site_Code__c);
            }
            c.Site_Code__c = siteId;
        }
    }

    public static String clean(String dirtyCode){
        String cleanedCode = dirtyCode;
        while (cleanedCode.length() < 4) {
            cleanedCode = '0' + cleanedCode;
        }
        return cleanedCode;
    }


}
```

### Test class

```
@IsTest
private class SiteCoderTest {
    static TestMethod void siteCoderTest() {

        Account a1 = new Account(Name = '0123', Site_Code_Id__c = '0123');
        Account a2 = new Account(Name = '1234', Site_Code_Id__c = '1234');
        Account a3 = new Account(Name = '2345', Site_Code_Id__c = '2345');
        Account a4 = new Account(Name = '0002', Site_Code_Id__c = '0002');

        Case c1 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = '0123');
        Case c2 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = '1234');
        Case c3 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = null);
        Case c4 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = '2');

        List<Case> caseInsert = new List<Case>();
        List<Account> accountInsert = new List<Account>();

        accountInsert.add(a1);
        accountInsert.add(a2);
        accountInsert.add(a3);
        accountInsert.add(a4);

        caseInsert.add(c1);
        caseInsert.add(c2);
        caseInsert.add(c3);
        caseInsert.add(c4);

        insert accountInsert;
        insert caseInsert;

        Account ac1 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :a1.Id];
        Account ac2 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :a2.Id];
        Account ac3 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :a3.Id];
        Account ac4 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :a4.Id];
        Case cc1 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c1.Id];
        Case cc2 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c2.Id];
        Case cc3 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c3.Id];
        Case cc4 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :c4.Id];


        system.debug('SHOULD BE TRUE: ' + (string.valueof(cc1.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac1.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 1: ' + string.valueof(ac1.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 1: ' + string.valueof(cc1.Site_Code__c));

        system.debug('SHOULD BE TRUE: ' + (string.valueof(cc2.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac2.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 2: ' + string.valueof(ac2.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 2: ' + string.valueof(cc2.Site_Code__c));

        system.debug('SHOULD BE TRUE: ' + (string.valueof(cc3.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac3.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 3: ' + string.valueof(ac3.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 3: ' + string.valueof(cc3.Site_Code__c));

        system.debug('SHOULD BE FALSE: ' + (string.valueof(cc4.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac4.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 4: ' + string.valueof(ac4.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 4: ' + string.valueof(cc4.Site_Code__c));


        system.assert(string.valueof(cc1.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac1.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.assert(string.valueof(cc2.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac2.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.assertNotEquals(string.valueOf(cc3.Site_Code__c), string.valueOf(ac3.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.assert(string.valueOf(cc3.Site_Code__c) == string.valueOf(ac4.Site_Code_Id__c));
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a null check whenever you access any methods or a variable like string or list. I prefer `String.isNotEmpty(yourVariable)` variant as it does empty and null checks.

Comment: @RahulSharma that appears to have fixed the error. If you submit as an answer I will accept, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000063739) - this is most common problem. It occurs when you do not have a null/empty check for variable like String, List, etc.

Always have a habit to do a null check to make your solution more robust as sometimes its hard to debug and can be time consuming.

In your case you can use `!= null`; I prefer `String.isNotEmpty()`:

```
if (String.isNotEmpty(sitecode) && sitecode.length() < 4){
    // your code
}
```

Comment: The thing with using `String.isEmpty()` and `String.isNotEmpty()` is that it also captures empty strings (not just nulls). In this situation, I'd assume that OP wants to run this operation on empty (bu non-null) strings. Just one more thing to consider.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, null pointer exceptions (NPEs) are *fun* (by which I mean they are no fun at all).

The gist of the error is that your code ends up trying to evaluate something of the form `null.someMethod()`.

`null` is a special instance/value of a special datatype (the `Any` type). Just about every class (if not every class) in Apex has it a part of their class hierarchy. This is why you can pass `null` into a method where it expects an `Integer`, `String`, `Decimal`, etc...

The thing about `null`, though, is that it has no methods of its own (this is a gross simplification. The actual explanation requires a decent bit of knowledge about compilers, type systems, and Object-Oriented theory, which is *way* beyond the scope here). Try to call a method on a `null`, and you get an NPE.

So, you're getting an NPE, that means you must be operating on a null somewhere...but where?

Let's look at the relevant snippet of your code:

```java
    for (Case c : newList) {
        String sitecode = c.Web_Site_Code__c;
        if (sitecode.length() < 4){      //  Line 14
            clean(sitecode);
        }
        codes.add(sitecode);
        System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Site code added to lookup: ' + sitecode);
    }
```

`sitecode.length() < 4`, no `null` there, right?

Not exactly.

`sitecode` is initialized using `c.Web_Site_Code__c`. If you have a case with no value for `Web_Site_Code__c`, then you'll get a `null` when you use it to set the value of `sitecode`.

Your code then effectively becomes:

```java
    for (Case c : newList) {
        String sitecode = null;//c.Web_Site_Code__c;
        if (null.length() < 4){      //  Line 14
            clean(null);
        }
        codes.add(null);
        System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Site code added to lookup: ' + null);
    }
```

And there we have it, `null.length()`, the source of your NPE.

There are a variety of ways to mitigate the risk of encountering an NPE, the most common is just adding a null check of some fashion to prevent you from calling a method on null.

```java
// This method takes advantage of short-circuit evaluation
// If Salesforce can determine the outcome of an expression before evaluating the
//   entire thing, Salesforce will skip evaluating the rest of an expression.
// From boolean algebra, False && <anything> == False
// If sitecode IS null, the first part of the expression is false
// False && <anything> == False, so we can stop evaluating at this point
// This means we never try to evaluate null.length(), and we avoid an NPE
if (sitecode != null && sitecode.length() < 4){      //  Line 14
    clean(sitecode);
}
```

Comment: Beautifully explained Derek!